# Making Simple Single Color Images from HEX value list

Tags: image, hex, rgb

I am a total noob when it comes to programming. But I have a situation (or rather two, but lets start with the easier one first) that seems like programming would be right up its alley, but I have no idea how to do it, or even how to run such a program. Hoping someone can help.

I have a list of several hundred HEX (or RGB) values (thankfully I know what those are) and I need to make .png images of 99x99 pixels out of each of them. Each color also has a name, which the files needs to be saved as.

What I have:  Vivid Sapphire 0040FF

Should create a small square .png image named Vivid Sapphire.png, with dimensions 99x99 pixels and show just the color 0040FF.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ppmmake](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/ppmmake.1.html) and [pnmtopng](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/pnmtopng.1.html):

```
while read line
do  ppmmake \#${line##* } 99 99 | pnmtopng >"${line% *}".png
done <list.txt
```

On Windows 10, you can install Ubuntu from the *Microsoft Store*. Then from the Ubuntu terminal window, you can install [ppmmake](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/ppmmake.1.html) and [pnmtopng](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/pnmtopng.1.html) by entering

```
sudo apt install netpbm
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

(`dos2unix` for convenience since your data file probably has *DOS line endings*).

Then if for example your *list* is contained in the file `list.txt` in the folder `C:\Users\Public\Documents`, the command becomes:

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/Public/Documents
dos2unix <list.txt |
while read line
do  ppmmake \#${line##* } 99 99 | pnmtopng >"${line% *}".png
done
```

Comment: Ok, I figured something WAS possible for this. Thank you for the answer.  The problem is I know literally nothing about Linux/Ubuntu/ppmmake or how to even run such a program. Consider me like a curious, wide eyed 5 year old...  I have a Windows 10 platform and never tried Linux, and only brief forays with Apple products.

Comment: I added instructions for Windows 10.